# Node.js, mongo, promises - passing an argument to the then function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

Using node.js, with promises instead of callbacks, to retrieve a user object from mongo, by specifying the user id.  Db access uses `require('mongodb').Db`.

The calls start at the bottom of the below code: `findByIdPromise(userId)`
`collection.findOne()` requires the userId as an argument, but `then()` calls a function with the promise as the single argument.

To get around this limitation, I pass `then()` an object `finder` which has the userId property preset, and a function `findUser` which takes the collection promise, and calls the collection's `findOne`, passing it the preset userId.

Is this a half decent way to do it?

```
UserProvider.prototype.getCollectionPromise = function () {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var resolve = deferred.resolve;

    var collectionCallback = function (error, usersCollection) {
        if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        } else {
            resolve(usersCollection);
        }
    };
    this.db.collection(CollectionName, collectionCallback);
    return deferred.promise;
};

UserProvider.prototype.findOnePromise = function () {
    var userId;
    var setUserId = function (id) { this.userId = id; };

    var deferred = q.defer();
    var resolve = deferred.resolve;

    var findUser = function (coll) {
        coll.findOne(
            { _id: id },
            function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    throw new Error(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            }
        );
    };
    return deferred.promise;
};

UserProvider.prototype.findByIdPromise = function(id) {
    var finder = new UserProvider.findOnePromise();
    finder.setUserId(id);

    return this.getCollectionPromise().then(finder.findUser);
};
```

Comment: "Best" is very subjective, as I wouldn't try to layer a promise API over the MongoDB API.

Comment: Hi WiredPrairie, I can't say I thought that line of the post would be critiqued.  I've changed "best" to "half decent" so as not to suggest I think my solution might be competitively outstanding.  I'm new to node, mongo and promises, so scratching my head.  Why wouldn't you use promises with Mongo?

Comment: @10cls Most of the libraries written for node use callbacks rather than promises.  As far as I have seen, all of the standard libraries do so.  You're going to end up wrapping almost every library you want to use in order to convert it to promises, which is an awful lot of unnecessary effort.

Comment: 10cls, does the code actually work? I'm guessing that it doesn't for various reasons, but your question is phrased as a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) not a "please help me fix it". I'm confused.

Comment: Hi Beetroot, I haven't run it yet.  I was uncallbacking the code which calls this code and found I was having to use the same (anti)pattern to pass an argument.  Figured I should ask how this situation should be dealt with - the (anti)pattern works, but I suspect it's conceptually square peg, round hole, or wrong, or non-idiomatic, or clumsy, and requiring fixing.  Hope the confusion clears up.

Comment: Hi Aaron, sounds like you've hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @Aaron, you may as well post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing asynchronous work in Node.js is by a callback, usually the last argument to a function, that takes an error as its first argument and any following arguments as return values.  This is made standard by the standard libraries (i.e. built-in packages), as well as most of the popular npm modules using this style.

You are, of course, completely welcome to use promises if you prefer.  However, I would advise against it; you are going to end up wrapping almost every library you use in order to convert it from callbacks to promises, which will not be a particularly fun exercise.

Note: The only exception I know that uses promises and is fairly popular is `selenium-webdriver`.  As far as I can tell, it uses promises so that code written using it looks as similar as possible to the other selenium libraries, which are all synchronous.

Comment: Yeah I concur with aaron.  If you're going to use node you're probably also going to be using a lot of npm libraries, and fighting with convention is just going to add to your headaches (and we don't need more of those with async programming ;).  Would recommend you check out caolan's async library to deal with complexity: https://npmjs.org/package/async

Comment: With q (https://github.com/kriskowal/q) you can use both promise-style + callback-style without an extra effort using Q.nodeify. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20153874/12388 or this real-world example https://github.com/palmerabollo/rest-confidence-client/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Promises are a part of ES6, a part of Chrome, and will most likely make their way into the core of node.js.  They work fine with all kinds of libraries, and support continues to grow in node libraries.  Also as Guido said, q allows you to wrap node style function(err,data) callbacks with ease.